What is this usage of のよ?

The character meets a girl at a party and she tells him this. I understand it's "Please eat a lot, I'll bring some to you"
But what is the second part of the sentence actually? "let me hear about your recommendations"? why is のよ used?

あんのよ is the verb ある with the explanatory no. The る has contracted to ん. This way of using explanatory no (without the copula だ) is feminine. あるんだよ or あんだよ would be masculine.

おすすめあんのよ I have a recommendation
まかせて Leave it to me


I think you misread まかせて as きかせて. 「おすすめあんのよ、まかせて」 is straightforwardly 'I've got [some] recommendation[s], just leave this to me'.
